# How to select multiple values as a single value from the same table (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have this table named available_service_information (this is just a part of it):

```
| service_provider | correlation_id | service_transaction_code | did_service_transaction_code | transaction_currency | service_type |
|------------------|----------------|--------------------------|------------------------------|----------------------|--------------|
| CA JONES         | 123456         | JONES-NORMAL             | JNSNRML                      | USD                  | MANAGED      |
| CA JONES         | 123456         | JONES-NORMAL             | JNSNRML                      | USD                  | SELF         |
| CA JONES         | 123456         | JONES-EXTRA              | JNSXTRA                      | USD                  | MANAGED      |
| CA JONES         | 123456         | JONES-EXTRA              | JNSXTRA                      | USD                  | ALL-INCLUDED |
```

And from the data of this table I need to construct a json string that looks like this:

```
{
  "service_provider": "CA JONES",
  "service_code" : ["JONES-NORMAL", "JONES-EXTRA"],
  "correlation_id": "123456",
  "available_service_data": [
    {
      "service_transaction_code": "JONES-NORMAL",
      "did_service_transaction_code": "JNSNRML",
      "transaction_currency": "USD",
      "service_datasets": [
        {"service_type": "MANAGED"},
        {"service_type": "SELF"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "service_transaction_code": "JONES-EXTRA",
      "did_service_transaction_code": "JNSXTRA",
       "transaction_currency": "USD",
       "service_datasets": [
        {"service_type": "MANAGED"},
        {"service_type": "ALL-INCLUDED"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The idea is to get the data based on the correlation_id. How can I select multiple values from this table as a single value? For example, would it be possible to do something like:

```
SELECT service_transaction_code AS service_code
FROM available_service_information
WHERE correlation_id = '123456'
```

And the same thing for available_service_data and service_datasets. I want to have a single query that does something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
service_provider,
service_transaction_code AS service_code,
correlation_id,
(SELECT DISTINCT
  service_transaction_code,
  did_service_transaction_code,
  transaction_currency,
  (SELECT DISTINCT
     service_type
   FROM available_service_information
   WHERE service_transaction_code = 'service_transaction_code selected in the previous query'
   AND did_service_transaction_code = 'did_service_transaction_code selected in the previous query'
   AND transaction_currency = 'transaction_currency selected in the previous query'
  AS service_datasets)
AS available_service_data
FROM available_service_information
WHERE correlation_id = '123456')
FROM available_service_information
```

How could I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Also, if I wanted to store the service_code to this table with multiple service_transaction_code how could I do that (I mean store it as a list with service transaction codes). Would I need to store it as jsonb or are there other options?

Comment: SQL Server <> PostgreSQL - please correct your tags.

Comment: Honestly, all of them did not match my specific cases

Comment: Good point, will do

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object( 'service_provider', r.service_provider
                         , 'service_code', array_agg(DISTINCT r.service_transaction_code)
                         , 'correlation_id', r.correlation_id 
                         , 'available_service_data', array_agg(r.arr)
                         )
FROM
(
SELECT correlation_id
     , service_transaction_code
     , service_provider
     , transaction_currency
     , jsonb_build_object( 'service_transaction_code', service_transaction_code
                         , 'did_service_transaction_code', did_service_transaction_code
                         , 'transaction_currency', transaction_currency
                         , 'service_datasets', array_agg(jsonb_build_object('service_type', service_type))
                         ) AS arr
  FROM available_service_information
 GROUP BY correlation_id, service_transaction_code, service_provider, did_service_transaction_code, transaction_currency
) AS r
GROUP BY r.correlation_id, r.service_provider, r.correlation_id
```

Result :

```
{ "service_code": ["JONES-EXTRA", "JONES-NORMA"]
, "correlation_id": 123456
, "service_provider": "CA JONES"
, "available_service_data": [ {"service_datasets": [ {"service_type": "MANAGED"}
                                                   , {"service_type": "SELF"}
                                                   ]
                              , "transaction_currency": "USD"  
                              , "service_transaction_code": "JONES-NORMA"
                              , "did_service_transaction_code": "JNSNRML"
                              }
                            , {"service_datasets": [ {"service_type": "MANAGED"}
                                                   , {"service_type": "ALL-INCLUDED"}
                                                   ]
                              , "transaction_currency": "USD"
                              , "service_transaction_code": "JONES-EXTRA"
                              , "did_service_transaction_code": "JNSXTRA"
                              }
                            ]
 }
```

see the test in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bb6148a818211127b1c6289c66b70966)